# What does replace cakephp2 datasource in cakephp4?

Tags: datasource, cakephp-4.x

I'm trying to make API calls to my web hosting (ovh) in order to create email alias and email accounts.
Some years ago I did that in Cakephp2 using Datasource, but now I'm using cakephp4 and I'm not sure how to proceed...

How can I create a Model without a database Table ?

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to just not go down that route, IMHO you'll be much better off if you create a simple custom service around the API instead, there's no need to make all datasources look like CakePHP database/ORM "repositories" (I put that in quotes because CakePHP's repositories should not be confused with what repositories are in the context of the repository pattern).

If there was really, really, really a need for it, I'd say first go look into **[muffin/webservice](https://github.com/UseMuffin/Webservice)**, which shoulders some of the work required for you. And if you wanted to know how to do it completely on your own, well you'd have to implement `\Cake\Datasource\RepositoryInterface` accordingly, which comes with lots of baggage and is anything but straightforward.

If you want to see how that could look like, I'd again refer to `muffin/webservice`, check for example its **[`Endpoint` repository](https://github.com/UseMuffin/Webservice/blob/3.0.0/src/Model/Endpoint.php)** and the surrounding classes, that should give you an idea of the "how to" and the complexity involved.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I was trying to figure it out with muffin/webservice and indeed it seemed quite complex in the structure. But is there a way to create Model/Table without a DB table ? I need to create a Model/Table to validate the fields of email accounts and alias, isn't it ?

Comment: @Oliv As mentioned, you'd have to implement `\Cake\Datasource\RepositoryInterface`, similar to what `muffin/webserivce` does. The "new" ORM is nothing like the 2.x patchwork that allowed abuse at every step of the way, there's no simple and clean equivalent to "tableless models" provided by the CakePHP 3.x+ ORM. However you don't need to create a repository-ish interface to wrap APIs, just drop that idea and go back the basics. Validators can be used manually wherever you please, check the [**`\CakePHP\Validation`**](https://api.cakephp.org/4.4/namespace-Cake.Validation.html) namespace.